# Which relative path is necessary

Tags: java, path

My java file is for example has such path `com.company.project.util` and file `javaClass.java`. In this file I write procedure to read another file, which is in the folder `META-INF/example.xml`.

Both this folders `com.company.project.util` and `META-INF` are in the same folder `src`.
Which relative path I have to pass into this javaClass.java to achieve example.xml? How many times it is necessary to use `../`? Cause I am a little bit confused with this big package name.

Comment: Are you loading a file using a FileInputStream, or getResourceAsStream() as Jayesh's answer explains, or some other mechanism?

Comment: @Will, using FileReader

Comment: Then it depends on where you're invoking the Java program. That's the working directory. If you're not sure of the working directory, you can System.out.println(new File().getAbsolutePath());

Answer (score 0):

If running the program from the package root (src) and using FileReader as mentioned, you would use simply "META-INF/example.xml". Modify this path as appropriate if the working directory is different.

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you example

My Test1 class is in default package and my resources folder is in src folder, I am able to access resource. you can map your need as per that.

public class Test1 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Test1();  
}
Test1(){
    BufferedInputStream file= (BufferedInputStream) this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("resources/a.txt");
    try {
        System.out.println((char)file.read());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Also, if your java class is in any package then you can go to class path using "../" as one step back for each folder. once you reach class path, give path of resource.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is in your source folder then it's on your classpath, you'll be able to load it with an absolute path as a resource:

```
this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/example.xml");
```